# What causes the readable field to be set to false in express.js request?

Tags: javascript, express

New to expressjs and trying to debug the following issue I'm having locally:

1. The GET /health endpoint check works with 200 status response
2. the POST /login endpoint doesn't even appear to fire when running locally (I added a "console.log" statement in the corresponding controller function that would be called by the express.js router and it never gets fired) - what I notice when I do `console.log(req)` in the main error handler is that this `readable` field is marked `false` whereas in the /health endpoint it's marked true:

```
    req: IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: ReadableState {
          objectMode: false,
          highWaterMark: 16384,
          buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
          length: 0,
          pipes: null,
          pipesCount: 0,
          flowing: true,
          ended: true,
          endEmitted: true,
          reading: false,
          sync: false,
          needReadable: false,
          emittedReadable: false,
          readableListening: false,
          resumeScheduled: false,
          emitClose: true,
          autoDestroy: false,
          destroyed: false,
          defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
          awaitDrainWriters: null,
          multiAwaitDrain: false,
          readingMore: false,
          decoder: null,
          encoding: null,
          [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
        },
        readable: false,
```

This just started happening in the past day or so so it's really baffling what change could have been made that would affect the POST /login endpoint's ability to fire when the server is run locally.

Comment: Sure, that's fair, was hoping to get some ideas or if there were sort common "gotchas" in the expressjs community to watch out for. Looking over the past week's changes, I didn't see any configuration changes that are likely culprits, so being new to expressjs I was also hoping to use this question to get some ideas.

Comment: If the error handler is called, don't look at the request but at the error. To solve your problem, we need to see your server code as well as the request you're sending.

Answer (score 0):

An express request is a [`IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) which is a [readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams) and inherits its [`.readable` property](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_readable):

> Is `true` if it is safe to call `readable.read()`, which means the stream has not been destroyed or emitted 'error' or 'end'.

In short it means that the stream has not yet been completely consumed. Since the body of a GET request is ignored (it has none), none of your middlewares will have read it, in contrast to the POST request. So this is expected, and doesn't help with your actual problem.